# Specifying a merge function in pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, merge

Can a merge criteria function be specified in pandas?

So instead of just matching two fields, specifying a function that will return true or false to determine if _merge is ‘both’ or the alternatives?

Comment: Could you add an example? I guess you could do an outer merge and then filter

Comment: I do not think this is possible check this https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/7480 I think you have to preprocess your dataframes first then apply merge.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you can do this:

```
pd.merge(df1,df2, on = 'your_var' how = 'outer', indicator = True)
```

You can then just look at _merge variable and it will show.